# How to import other file using relative path to executed file not python command path?

Tags: python

My folder trees:

```
./
├── README.MD
├── basic
│   └── thresh.py
├── images
│   └── figure.jpg
└── utils
    ├── util.py
    └── util.pyc
```

I want to import `util.py` in `thresh.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../utils')
import util
```

When I run command `$ python thresh.py` in the `basic` folder, it's allright. But run `$ python ./basic/thresh.py` in the topmost folder, I will get the error:

> ImportError: No module named util

So how to make `$ python ./basic/thresh.py` and `$ python thresh.py` both work to import file by given the file's relative path to executed file regardless of python command path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the absolute path of the script you are executing with (there are other variants also using `__file__`, but this should work)

```
import os
wk_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
print( wk_dir )
```

and then get your dir with it, e.g.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(wk_dir+'/../utils')
```

PS: You might need to use `__file__` instead of `'__file__'`.

Comment: This work. But you need change `'__file__'` to `__file__` in your code.

Comment: @tomfriwel - The code posted was tested and it works. I found it somehwere else too. The change you suggest does not work for me, although I have seen other posts using it similarly. I did not explore this in detail, but the important points are: 1) you solved your problem, 2) others are aware that they might need to try both.

Comment: Maybe we use different version of Python.